# Regex for capturing command flags and values

Tags: regex

I'm trying to make a Regex to capture command flags and values. So for example, given the string:

`helloworld --name=stretch --message="Hi there everyone"`

It should capture `name` and `stretch`, and then `message` and `Hi there everyone`.

So I've almost got what I need:

`\--([a-zA-Z]+)=[\"\']*([^\"\s\'\\]*(?:\\.[^\\\'\"]*)*)\g`

But I'm having issues with the space ... If I take it out, it only works properly with quoted values, and with it in it only works with unquoted strings Lol ...

Here's the regex101:
https://regex101.com/r/eE1zP6/2

Comment: Is there a possibility to escape the quote inside a quoted string? If not, I guess `--([a-zA-Z]+)=([^"'\s]+|"[^"]*"|'[^']*')` should do it.

Comment: Yeah I was trying to make it so that is accepts escaped quotes too

Comment: Sorry for asking, but how do you escape quotes?

Comment: "my name is \"chris\" :D"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of juggling around with quotes, take **a far superior approach**: use a *conditional* regex.
The basic form is as follows:

```
(?(1)foo|bar)
# Meaning: if group1 is set, use foo, otherwise bar as subpattern
```

For your requirements, this comes down to:

```
--(?P<key>\w+)=(")?(?P<value>(?(2)[^"]+|[^\s]+))
```

In `PHP` code and with explanation, this looks even more beautiful:

```
<?php
$string = 'helloworld --name=stretch --message="Hi there everyone"';
$regex = '~
            --(?P<key>\w+)=         # look for two dashes, capture every word character into the group "key"
            (")?                    # look for double quotes and make the group (2) optional
            (?P<value>              # save the following to the group "value"
                (?(2)[^"]+|[^\s]+)  # if (2) is set, capture everything BUT a double quote
                                    # else capture everything but a space (not allowed without quotes)
            )
            ~x';                    # verbose modifier
preg_match_all($regex, $string, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
foreach ($matches as $match)
    echo "Key: {$match['key']}, Value: {$match['value']}\n";
/* output:
Key: name, Value: stretch
Key: message, Value: Hi there everyone
*/    
?>
```

See a demo for this one on <kbd>[ideone.com](http://ideone.com/8H25vN)</kbd>.

You can even go further and allow **single quotes as delimiter** and have **escaped quotes in your values** like so:

```
--(?P<key>\w+)= 
(['"])?                   # allow single or double quotes
(?P<value>       
    (?(2).+?(?<!\\)(?=\2) # if (2) is set, match everything lazily afterwards
                          # and make sure that what follows is the formerly captured quote
                          # make also sure that what precedes, is not a backslash (thus allowing escaped quotes)
    |[^\s]+)
)
```

See this <kbd>[demo on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/gE1hG6/3)</kbd> (hijacked from @SebastianProske, sorry mate :).

Comment: this doesn't take into account single quotes and escaped quotes (though i like the approach)

Comment: @SebastianProske: Look at the updated answer at the bottom and your example changed with it (hijacked it) :)

Comment: taking a few steps more, but looking much prettier - so i will let my answer stay and upvote yours

Comment: @SebastianProske Thanks.

Comment: Very cool thanks. I ended up using this one Lol. Although I did have to edit it slightly to get it to work in php (adding a few extra backslashes): `$pattern='/--(?P<key>\w+)=([\'"])?(?P<value>(?(2).+?(?<!\\\\)(?=\2)|[^\s]+))/'`

Comment: @Stretch: Yes, you need to escape the backslash for `PHP`, I forgot to mention that. Glad it helped though.

Answer (score 4):

If it's suitable, you could capture the quoted and unquoted messages in different groups:

```
--(\w+)=(?:[\"\']([^\"\'\\]*(?:\\.[^\\\'\"]*)*)[\"\']|(\w+))
```

Then in your code you can check if it's a quoted (group 2) or unquoted (group 3).

Comment: @Stretch can you edit your question to include that requirement?

Comment: It's in my first regex ... But yeah okay

Comment: @Stretch edited my answer, now it should work with escaped quotes :) https://regex101.com/r/mN1wG0/1

Comment: Cool that should work :D Thanks ... I slightly edited it, so that if it's not in quotes, you can still have all characters except space :D - `--(\w+)=(?:[\"\']([^\"\'\\]*(?:\\.[^\\\'\"]*)*)[\"\']|([^ ]*))`

Answer (score 1):

My approach would be the following:

```
--([a-zA-Z]+)=([^"'\s]+|"(?:[^"\\]|\\.)*"|'(?:[^'\\]|\\.)*')
```

The start is quite simple: `--([a-zA-Z]+)=` matches double `-` followed by letters and =, capturing the letters in a group.
Then we have 3 alternatives, without quotes it is `[^"'\s]+` matching everything thats not a quote or space (you might remove the quotes if they are allowed inside the value. `"(?:[^"\\]|\\.)*"` is looking for a double quote followed by any amount of non-double quotes or `\` followed by anything until there is an double quote that is not eaten by the `\.`. `'(?:[^'\\]|\\.)*'` is doing the same for single quotes. This allows the (in my opinion correct) mixing of quotes as shown in the last line of my example.

https://regex101.com/r/gE1hG6/2

Comment: Plus one for hijacking your regex example :)

Answer (score 0):

If not using `IF` conditional match, you could try:

```
--(\w+)=(?:('|")(.*?)(?<!\\)\2|(\S+))
```

[DEMO HERE](https://regex101.com/r/zI0iJ8/2)

Comment: `('|")` is the same as `['"]`, also `\S+` is exactly the same as `[^\s]+`. Additionally, more steps are needed with this approach (because of the `.*?`).